# Xubuntu(or xfce in general) minimize button disappears on Intellij Idea if more then one instance is launched

Tags: xfce, intellij

Can someone give a hint on this one? The minimize button simply disappears and from the left top context menu the "minimize" is shown as grey.

Comment: Which release?   (ie. I'm wondering what version of XFCE and GTK+ you are using)

Comment: Xfce 4.12(basic from Xubuntu 18.04.3), libgtk-3-0:amd 3.22.30-1ubu amd64

Answer (score 0):

It's been reported to JetBrains and they said it was a problem with Xfce 4.12:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007000280-Minimize-button-disappears

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-565

They said the solution would be to upgrade to Xubuntu 19.10, which uses Xfce 4.14.